# How to place tabs at bottom of screen with bottom navbar in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm already using bottom navigation bar in app. For one composable screen, I need to place tabs at bottom of screen (above bottom bar) and its content to above tabs. How do I achieve that setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Scaffold` with a bottomBar:

```
Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    bottomBar = {
        BottomAppBar() {
            //....
        }
    },
    content = { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(bottom = innerPadding.calculateBottomPadding()),
        ) {
           
            Column( modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)){
                //Content
            }

            TabRow(selectedTabIndex = state) {
                //....
            }
        }
    }
)
```

[image]